# What is a 15-12G, should a person try to sell their stock when a company files this?

Tags: stocks

What does a 15-12G mean, is that a bad thing, should we try to sell out?

I read the following and seem to think that the stock may be good and this is the company asking the securities and exchange commission to not have to report anything anymore.

The stock is a total penny stock scam anyway but I was hopeful it would bounce like if did for the past 3 years.

Not sure if I should or can mention the actual stock, but I am happy to share.

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sec-form-15-12g.asp

Comment: As I understand it, 15-12g is "We are taking this stock off the market." Usually that means there isn't enough of the company left to justify the expense of maintaining records and filing the necessary forms. Occasionally it can be because the company has been absorbed into another, but you'd have heard about it if that was the case. I think the answer is that your longshot has just crashed and burned.

Comment: And, if course, if it is being taken off the market you would have an ... Interesting ... challenge finding a way to sell it at any price.

Comment: @keshlam Trying to understand your reply, obviously not an answer, curious where your source came from, I am not finding anything to matches your response "We are taking this stock off the market."?

Comment: Websearch for the form name finds many descriptions of its use. I rephrased/synthesized a bit to get that brief summary; it isn't a direct quote... but the descriptions were clear enough that I'm pretty darned confident if it. If I'm wrong, someone will post a correction. (Though I should probably make this an Answer rather than Comment if folks do agree with me.)

Comment: @keshlam: SEC Form 15-12G is a form that allows for certification of termination of registration of a class of security under Section 12(g) or notice of suspension of duty to file reports pursuant to Sections 13 and 15(d) of the

Comment: If it isn't registered the market won't deal with it, though it may still be transferred if you can somehow get interested parties together. Not reporting will get one deregistered.